# CONVERTIR ARREGLO DE BYTES A ARCHIVO .NET

Tags: vb.net, archivo, byte

quería saber si alguien sabe como convertir un arreglo de bytes a un archivo, gracias de antemano,

```
'ESTE ES EL ARREGLO DE BYTES QUE ESTA ALMACENADO EN LA BASE DE DATOS
        Dim bytes As Byte() = elDato(0).Item("archivo") 

'AQUI LO PASO A STRING
                Dim strBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)

       'AHORA QUE LO TENGO LA PARTE QUE ME FALTA ES ESTA COMO CONVIERTO ESO A UN ARCHIVO(independientemente que sea word, excel o pdf)
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

`System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("fichero", bytes);`

O si lo que quieres es guardar la cadena en base64

`System.IO.File.WriteAllText("fichero", strBase64);`